# Adobe Illustrator - Apply brush to single stroke in appearance panel

Tags: adobe-illustrator, brush, graphic-styles

Trying to create a graphic style.  Basically, it is multiple strokes applied with different widths, opacity, etc.  I wanted to see if it was possible to apply a brush to a single stroke within the style - in other words, one of the stroke items on the appearance panel.  There doesn't seem to be an obvious way to do this.  Using CC 2021.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure.

Highlight the stroke in the **Appearance Panel**...

.. Click the Brush you want to apply.

The brush should only be applied to the stroke you highlighted.

[image] [image]

If you *don't* highlight a stroke, the brush will typically be applied to the *topmost* stroke in the appearance stack. i.e the first stroke.

Comment: Thank you.  In retrospect, it seems obvious, but I was stupiding I guess.  Thanks!

Comment: @dgo .. we've *all* been there :) No Worries!